# How to read data from a Realm Object server?

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have Realm Object server and I have created a new Realm and named it as **Test**. I have created a new table inside it called **Water**.

Here are my URLS:

```
public static final String AUTH_URL = "https://" + INSTANCE_ADDRESS + "/auth";
public static final String REALM_URL = "realms://" + INSTANCE_ADDRESS + "/Test";
```

Here is my code that I am trying to read data from Water table:

```
SyncCredentials credentials = SyncCredentials.nickname(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), true);
SyncUser.logInAsync(credentials, AUTH_URL, new SyncUser.Callback<SyncUser>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(SyncUser user) {
    SyncConfiguration syncConfiguration = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, Constants.REALM_URL)
        .build();
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(syncConfiguration);
    results = realm.where(Water.class).findAllAsync();
    callback.onSyncedUser(user.getIdentity());
  }
  @Override
  public void onError(ObjectServerError error) {
    callback.onRealmError(error.getErrorMessage());
  }
});
```

The issue is that I am getting always 0 results, but I am quite sure that I have data on the server since I have entered it manually.

Can somebody help?

Comment: You need to wait for a query to finish. Have you tried adding a RealmChangeListener?

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem. Can you post it as an answer? I would like to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for a query to finish. Have you tried adding a RealmChangeListener?

Async queries only return *after* some time.

If that wouldn't have worked, I would have told you to use `waitForInitialRemoteData()` combined with `Realm.getInstanceAsync`.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept it. One more question: I get returned objects from Realm, but my POJO attributes are empty, while I can see values in some kind of ProxyState. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I've closed about 17 questions about that as duplicate and it's because proxy objects don't load data into fields. You need to debug-call the accessors. With Kotlin though, it's a bit tacky because you have to cast to the specific RealmProxy instance then call the `realm$getSomeField` method. Regular field access in your code will also work, it's just the debugger that's quirky.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day.